# Quickblox android message read/delivery status issue (Quickblox SDK 2.3.1)

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

Recently I have upgraded Quickblox Android SDK from 2.3 to 2.3.1. After this upgrade, message read/deliver status is not working in my application. please someone help me. It was working properly in my old versions :( . After a lot of debugging I have found that the message status updation is not hitting in any of the methods provided by the SDK  i.e. processMessageDelivered(String messageId, String dialogId, Integer userId) and processMessageRead(String messageId, String dialogId, Integer userId).

I have done the following to make it work. But still not working. Please help.

1. chatMessage.setMarkable(true);
2. When the user reads (at receiver end) a message, then send a read status QBPrivateChat.readMessage(chatMessage);
3. Still the listener is not getting invoked on the sender side. :(

UPDATE: If I reload all messages from Quickblox server, then I can see that all messages have Read/Delivery status. The problem is with the listener and I am not able to process the status at realtime.

Please check the code part below:

**Sending private message:**

```
public void sendPrivateMessage(QBChatMessage chatMessage, int opponentId, String dialogId) throws QBResponseException {
        chatMessage.setMarkable(true);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(dialogId)) {
            chatMessage.setProperty(ChatUtils.PROPERTY_DIALOG_ID, dialogId);
        }
        chatMessage.setRecipientId(opponentId);
            QBPrivateChat privateChat = privateChatManager.getChat(opponentId);

            String error = null;
            try {
                if (privateChat == null) {
                    privateChat = createChatIfNotExist(opponentId);
                }
                privateChat.sendMessage(chatMessage);
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                error = context.getString(R.string.dlg_fail_connection);
            } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                error = context.getString(R.string.dlg_fail_connection);
            }
      savePrivateMessageToCache(chatMessage, dialogId);
    }
```

**method to update read status to server**

```
  public void updateStatusMessageReadServer(String dialogId,QBChatMessage chatMessage, boolean fromPrivate) throws Exception {
        StringifyArrayList<String> messagesIdsList = new StringifyArrayList<String>();
        messagesIdsList.add(chatMessage.getId());
        QBChatService.markMessagesAsRead(dialogId, messagesIdsList);
         if (fromPrivate) {
        QBPrivateChat privateChat = privateChatManager.getChat(chatMessage.getSenderId());
        privateChat.readMessage(chatMessage);
         }
    }
```

**Receiver part in BaseChatHelper.java:**

```
 protected PrivateChatMessageListener privateChatMessageListener;
 public BaseChatHelper(Context context) {
        super(context);
        privateChatMessageListener = new PrivateChatMessageListener();
         initPrivacyListsManager();
    }


private class PrivateChatMessageListener implements
            QBMessageListener<QBPrivateChat>, QBMessageStatusListener {

        @Override
        public void processMessage(QBPrivateChat privateChat,
                                   final QBChatMessage chatMessage) {
            if (ChatUtils.isNotificationMessage(chatMessage)) {
                for (QBNotificationChatListener notificationChatListener : notificationChatListeners) {
                    notificationChatListener.onReceivedNotification(chatMessage
                            .getProperty(ChatUtils.PROPERTY_NOTIFICATION_TYPE)
                            .toString(), chatMessage);
                }
            } else {
                onPrivateMessageReceived(privateChat, chatMessage);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void processError(QBPrivateChat privateChat,
                                 QBChatException error, QBChatMessage originMessage) {
            // TODO: need to be implemented
        }


        @Override
        public void processMessageDelivered(String messageId, String dialogId, Integer userId) {
            updateMessageStatusDeliveredLocal(messageId, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void processMessageRead(String messageId, String dialogId, Integer userId) {
            try {
                MessageCache messageCache = new MessageCache();
                messageCache.setMessageId(messageId);
                messageCache.setRead(true);
                updateStatusMessageLocal(messageCache);
            } catch (QBResponseException e) {
                ErrorUtils.logError(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide your code, what methods do not work

Comment: Hi, please check the updated question. I have updated the codes with it. According to me, the deliver status should hit on method **processMessageDelivered(String messageId, String dialogId, Integer userId)** and read status should hit on method **processMessageRead(String messageId, String dialogId, Integer userId)** . But, I am not getting any responses in these methods. Please check my code and help me fixing this issue.  thanks :)

Comment: We have an updated version of read/delivered statuses API http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Read_status

Answer (score 0):

```
val messageStatusesManager = QBChatService.getInstance().messageStatusesManager
    messageStatusesManager.addMessageStatusListener(object : QBMessageStatusListener {
        override fun processMessageDelivered(messageId: String?, dialogId: String?, userId: Int?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "processMessageRead: Message READ : message ID $messageId")

        }

        override fun processMessageRead(messageId: String?, dialogId: String?, userId: Int?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "processMessageRead: Message READ : message ID $messageId")
        }
    })
```

https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/android-chat-messaging